# Why doesn't T.TryParse return a Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net

As far as I know, `int.TryParse(string, out int)` exists since Framework 2.0. So does `int?`.

Is there a reason to use an `out` parameter instead of returning an `int?` with `HasValue` set to `true` of `false` depending on the ability to convert ?

Comment: That would be a question for the .NET Framework development team. Most shops end up writing an extension method `string` called something along the lines of `ToNullableInt` implementing the behavior you desire themselves. I wouldn't be surprised if a future version of C# supports this natively.

Comment: Maybe because other languages do not have such a simple syntax for Nullables. E.g. in C++/CLI you have to write `Nullable<int> result = int::TryParse(...)`.

Comment: What reason do you have for treating any random string as `null`? Most potential uses I have seen of a conversion from `string` to `int?` are to convert an empty string to `null`, to convert a non-empty string to a valid `int`, and to reject random garbage like `@($^V@Q(%^%(@B^N(`. This would already not be a good fit for `int.TryParse`, regardless of its return type. Can you give a reasonable scenario in which `TryParse` returning `T?` is actually desirable?

Comment: I don't know why this wasn't done in the past, but C# 6 will have an alternative solution with [Declaration Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn683793.aspx) allowing you to do `int.TryParse(string, out int myInt)` without defining `myInt` beforehand.

Comment: In my mind the _Try_ part of the method name implies that the method will signal if the _Parse_ part succeeded or not. Just my opinion...

Comment: I seem to remember a blog post by Eric Lippert that mentioned that if they were building the `.TryParse()` methods today, they'd return `Nullable<T>`, but it didn't exist at the time (or was at least not as good as it is now). I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: If I was to hazard a guess, I'd say that one of *many* factors here could be that the `TryParse` stuff was separate to (and much more mature than) the generics stuff; IIRC, C# 2 / .NET 2 came close to shipping *without* generics (or worse: with type erasure), because getting it all to work was hard; it could be that the main 2.0 BCL changes (or at least, those not directly related to generics) had to work both with and without the inclusion of generics.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I cannot tell about the actual reasons, but I see three possible reasons:

1) [Nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) were introduced in .NET 2.0, while the [first `TryParse` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) were already around since .NET 1.1. Thus, when nullable types were introduced, it was too late for such an API change; and new classes wouldn't implement `TryParse` differently because the pattern had already been set.

2) Not all types can be used with the [`Nullable` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), only value types can. However, there are methods following the `Try*` pattern that have to return reference types. For example, a dictionary may totally legitimately contain `null` as an item, hence its [`TryGetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs an additional way to express that a key was not found.

3) The way the `Try*`-methods are written, it is possible to write code like this:

```
int myValue;
if (int.TryParse("42", out myValue)) {
    // do something with myValue
}
    // do something else
}
```

Now, imagine if `TryParse` only returned an `int?`. You can either dispose of the `myValue` variable and lose the result:

```
if (int.TryParse("42").HasValue) {
    // do something with ... what? You didn't store the conversion result!
}
    // do something else
}
```

Or you can add a nullable variable:

```
int? myValue = int.TryParse("42");
if (myValue.HasValue) {
    // do something with myValue.Value
}
    // do something else
}
```

This isn't an advantage over the current version any more, and instead it requires writing `myValue.Value` at some later instances, where otherwise a simple `value` would have sufficed. Note that in many cases, you *only* need the information about whether the operation was successful for the `if` statement.

Comment: 1) I didn't know `TryParse` methods existed in Framework 1.0. 2) I didn't thought of that. 3) The number of lines isn't a problem. It's just that I find the `out` keyword a bit... unnatural to use in C#.

Comment: @krimog: Sorry, I corrected 1.0 to 1.1, as I couldn't find a 1.0 example now (but the conclusion of the statement is till the same, obviously).

Comment: @krimog Why would using a language keyword be "unnatural" ?

Comment: @asawyer : Well, I don't really like methods changing my references. Of course it is a language keywork (otherwise we couldn't do that and we wouldn't talk about it). But even if sometimes it can really help, still, I usually prefer returning the new value. Just my opinion though.

Comment: @krimog I prefer immutable methods as well, but `out` has it's place. Even `goto` has it's use now and then.

Answer (score 24):

The simple reason is because when `int.TryParse` was added to the language, `Nullable<T>` didn't exist.

In [this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix/), there's a line towards the bottom that reads:

> The solution is to write your own extension method version of TryParse the way it would have been written had there been nullable value types available in the first place

which makes it clear that nullable types were not available to be used in the original implementation of `TryParse`. [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) was on the team that wrote the C# compiler, so I'd say that's a pretty authoritative source.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to find this ;)

Comment: Again Stackoverflow's Erik Lippert fanbase strikes again, just need to mention Eric Lippert and instant upvotes. :D

Comment: Who *else* can answer questions even when he's not answering questions?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quote from Julie Lerman's blog (Back from 2004):

> I have played with `nullable` in the March preview bits, but not yet in the May and disappointed with the current (but slated for serious improvement by the bcl team!!!) performance when I compared the using `nullable<t>` over current options. So for example with value types:
>
> comparing `myNullableInt.HasValue` to (in VB) is `myInt < 0`
>
> or with reference types
>
> comparing `myNullableThing.HasValue` to “`if not myThing=null`”
>
> the nullable type is **currently much much slower**. I have been **promised by a few on the BCL team** that the plan is to make the **nullable MUCH more performant**.
>
> I have also been given the hint that in the future, the following will be possible:
>
> ```
> Nullable<T> Parse(string value); 
> Nullable<Int32> i = Int32.Parse( some String );
> ```
>
> And will be more performant than `TryParse`. So that, too will be interesting.

I *assume* that as always, the benefit outweighs the cost.

Anyway, in the upcoming C# vNext, you can do:

```
DateTime.TryParse(s, out var parsedDateTime);
```

Turning TryParse into a one liner.

Comment: You can even now use a one-liner if you don't need a nullable: `DateTime dt = DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt) ? dt : DateTime.MinValue;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, but a rather lengthy one liner :)

Answer (score 4):

One other possible reason:

> Generics for .NET and C# in their current form almost didn't happen: it was a very close call, and the feature almost didn't make the cut for Whidbey (Visual Studio 2005). Features such as running CLR code on the database were given higher priority.
>
> ...
>
> Ultimately, an erasure model of generics would have been adopted, as for Java, since the CLR team would never have pursued a in-the-VM generics design without external help.

source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/03/15/net-c-generics-history-some-photos-from-feb-1999.aspx

My point being: the majority of changes in the BCL (or at least those not *directly* related to generics) probably needed to work both *with and without generics*, in case that feature was cut in the final RTM.

Of course, this also makes sense from a calling client perspective: all the consuming languages (ok, there weren't as many back then) would ideally have been able to use them - and `out` parameters weren't as cutting-edge as generics.

Answer (score 3):

As to reasons we can only guess, but some possible reasons are:

Assignment overhead: a boxed value incurs some (small) performance overhead over a built in type.

No real gains:

```
int res;
if int.TryParse("one", out res) {
  //something
}
```

isn't much worse than

```
int? res = int.TryParse("one");
if (res.HasValue){
  int realres = res.Value
  //something
}
```

Comment: This isn't "boxed"; at least, not in the usual meaning of boxing in .NET; an `int?` requires 8 bytes on the stack; an `int` and a `bool`: require 8 bytes on the stack... but: a `bool` and a `ref int` could actually take *12 bytes* on the stack (in x64) ;p Meaning: the `out` version actually takes more assignment, plus of course a few extra de-reference operations that aren't necessary in the other. My point: both have costs.

Comment: @MarcGravell : Doesn't `out` box the value ?

Comment: @krimog no, it does not; it simply passes the address of the field/local - which can be an address on the stack. It explicitly does not create a box.